# getting bad output from program. compiles without errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, syntax-error

```
here is my header file:
#ifndef weeklyEmp_h
#define weeklyEmp_h


// SPECIFICATION FILE weeklyEmp.h
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class weeklyEmp{
public:
//constructors
weeklyEmp();

weeklyEmp (string initName,
    double initHours,
    double initRate,
    int initExemptions,
    string initFilingStatus);

//--modifiers
void set_hours(double thisWeeksHours);
//post: Set the hours worked for a given week

void set_rate(double thisWeeksRate);
//post: Change the employee's hourly rate of pay

//--accessors
double grosPay () const;
//post: Return gross pay with overtime

double incomeTax() const;
//post: Return the federal income tax

double FICATax() const;
//post: Return the social security tax

string name() const;
//post: Return the employee's name

private:
    string my_name;
    double my_hours;
    double my_rate;
    int my_exemptions;
    string my_filingStatus;


    };

#endif //weeklyEmp_h
```

Here is an included .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "weeklyEmp.h"

using namespace std;

const double WEEKLY_ALLOWANCE = 39.42;
const double FICA_TAX_RATE = 0.0765;
weeklyEmp::weeklyEmp()
{
my_name = "?name?";
my_hours = 0.0;
my_rate = 0.0;
my_exemptions; 0;
my_filingStatus = "?filingStatus?";
}
weeklyEmp::weeklyEmp(string initName,
    double initHours,
    double initRate,
    int initExemptions,
    string initFilingStatus)
{
    my_name; initName;
    my_hours; initHours;
    my_rate; initRate;
    my_exemptions; initExemptions;
    my_filingStatus; initFilingStatus;
}

//--modifiers

void weeklyEmp::set_hours(double thisWeeksHours)
    //post: Set the hours worked for a given week
{
    my_hours = thisWeeksHours;
}



void weeklyEmp::set_rate(double thisWeeksRate)
//post: Change the employee's hourly rate of pay
{
 my_rate = thisWeeksRate;
}

//--accessors
double weeklyEmp::grosPay() const
//post: Return gross pay with overtime

{if(my_hours <=40) return my_hours * my_rate;
else
return (40*my_rate) + (my_hours-40) * 1.5 * my_rate;
}

double weeklyEmp::incomeTax() const
//post: Return the federal income tax
{
double result(0.0);
double taxableIncome(grosPay() - my_exemptions * WEEKLY_ALLOWANCE); 
if(my_filingStatus == "S" || my_filingStatus == "s")
{
if (taxableIncome <= 23.00)
result = 0.00;
else if(taxableIncome <= 397.00)
result = 0.15 * (taxableIncome - 23.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 928.00)
result = 56.10 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 397.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 2121.00)
result = 204.78 + 0.33 * (taxableIncome - 928.00);
else
result = 598.47 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 2121.00);
} 
if(my_filingStatus == "M" || my_filingStatus == "m")
{
if(taxableIncome <= 65.00)
result = 0.00;
else if(taxableIncome <= 689.00)
result = 0.15 * (taxableIncome - 65.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 1573.00)
result = 93.60 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 689.00);
else if(taxableIncome <= 3858.00)
result = 341.12 + 0.33 * (taxableIncome - 1573.00);
else
result = 1095.17 + 0.28 * (taxableIncome - 3858.00);
} 
/* round to the nearest penny */
/* include compfun.cpp for round function */
result = (result, 2);  
return result;

}

double weeklyEmp::FICATax() const
//post: Return the social security tax
{
    return grosPay() * FICA_TAX_RATE; 
}

string weeklyEmp::name() const
//post: Return the employee's name

{ 
 return my_name;

}
```

And finally the main cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "weeklyEmp.h"
#include "COMPFUN.H"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string name;
    double rate;
    double hours;
    int exemptions;
    string filingStatus;




    cout <<"Name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hourly Rate:";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "Hours Worked:";
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "Exemptions: ";
    cin >> exemptions;
    cout<< "S) ingle / M) arried: ";
    cin >> filingStatus;
    cout << endl;


weeklyEmp emp(name, hours, rate, exemptions, filingStatus);
double net = emp.grosPay() - emp.incomeTax() - emp.FICATax();




cout << "Employee: " << name << endl;
cout << "Gross  Income  FICA   Net" << endl;
decimals(cout, 2);
cout << emp.grosPay()  << emp.incomeTax() <<emp.FICATax()  <<net  << endl;

cout.width(9); cout << emp.grosPay();
cout.width(13); cout << emp.incomeTax() << endl;





system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the garbage output i am getting.  I think the error is in the .cpp file (not main, but included).  I cant find it.

Name: Mark
Hourly Rate:10
Hours Worked:10
Exemptions: 1
S) ingle / M) arried: S

Employee: Mark
Gross  Income  FICA   Net
85672853555216210000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.002.0065539732969740393000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000.00791188802582421710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: What is `my_name; initName;` etc supposed to do?  Cause what it does do, is pretty much nothing.  :P  I'm kinda thinking you want a `=` rather than a `;` between the two.

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure your problem is this constructor:

```
weeklyEmp::weeklyEmp(string initName,
    double initHours,
    double initRate,
    int initExemptions,
    string initFilingStatus)
{
    my_name; initName;
    my_hours; initHours;
    my_rate; initRate;
    my_exemptions; initExemptions;
    my_filingStatus; initFilingStatus;
}
```

It looks like you have `;` in place of `=` and so these members will have undetermined values since they are not being initialized. If you had warning enables it should have pointed out these lines. In `gcc` compiling with `-W -Wall -pedantic` gives these warning for those lines:

```
warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```